# Excel: Write a 1 or 0 value if condition is met

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Sorry if this has already been posted, but I just started today playing with Excel macros and I need a hand. I have a data column with values and I would like that if the conditions were met, the macro will return a 1, or 0 if it does not.

I have tried this but I am getting some error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim score As Integer, result As String

    score = Range("E2:E841").Value
    If score >= 20 Then
        result = "1"
    Else
        result = "0"
    End If

    Range("F2:F841").Value = result
End Sub
```

By the way, would it be possible to set a column as a condition? Like

- Condition 1: Column `A` must be higher than 20
- Condition 2: Column `B` must say yes

```
Column A      Column B        Result
   1             No             0
  20             Yes            1 
  30             No             1
```

Comment: If you are just trying to learn about Excel and macros, you could use an approach like this.  However, Excel does this with nothing but the test.  For example, cell A1 must say "yes": A1="yes" will be treated as 1 if true or 0 if false.  If you want the actual value 1 or 0: (A1="yes")*1 will produce the 1 or 0 result.  If that's what you want a cell to display, the cell would contain: =(A1="yes")*1 .  Otherwise, you can use it as part of a formula.

Comment: (1) You’re not going to get much help if you say “I am getting some error.”  You need to tell us what is happening.  (2) “>= 20” and “higher than 20” do not mean the same thing.  Please try to say what you mean, precisely.  (3) I guess from your 1/20/30 example data that you mean that you want Condition 1 ***AND*** Condition 2 to be true simultaneously (i.e., in the same row), but you don’t say.  Please try to say what you mean, precisely.  (4) As fixer1234 says, these computations can be done easily with worksheet functions/formulas.  For example, research the `AND()` function.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For any particular, practical problem, you should probably use worksheet functions/formulas if you can; at least, if it’s not incomprehensibly complicated.  If you’re trying to learn VBA for the sake of learning VBA, or in preparation for some larger effort that will require it, good for you; but it would be helpful if you said so.  Otherwise, if you post VBA routines that do things that can be done easily with worksheet functions/formulas, you’re going to get people suggesting that you use worksheet functions/formulas.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And, if you want help with Microsoft Excel, I suggest that you (a) look at Excel’s built-in help, and (b) search Super User for [microsoft-excel], [worksheet-function], and [vba].  Of course, a lot of what you find will be dull and boring; some will be enigmatic and unexplained; and some will be outright wrong.  You may get best results by focusing on answers written by [these people](http://superuser.com/help/badges/109/microsoft-excel).

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the code real quick -

```
Dim score As Integer
score = Range("E2:E841").Value
```

Type mismatch? Or something else? You can't set one integer to the value of a range of cells. You're going to need a loop -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim score As Range, result As String

    set score = Range("E2:E841")
    For each c in score
     If c >= 20 Then
        result = "1"
     Else
        result = "0"
     End If

     c.offset(,1) = result
    Next
End Sub
```